# Was Murder in Baldur's Gate a part of the D&D Next/5e playtest?

Tags: published-adventures, dnd-next-playtest

I have recently purchased *Murder in Baldur's Gate*, and downloaded the Monster Statistics supplement with the three-edition-stats for named NPC's (tough thugs, Flaming Fist Privates, etc).  These reflect a way to stat the NPC's depending upon which edition of the game this module would be plugged into.

The module was released in 2013, a period during the 5e/Next playtest and well before the PHB for 5th edition was released.

I was not yet back into the game/hobby at that point, and missed the playtest, so I have no point of reference on this.

**Was Murder in Baldurs's Gate official D&D next playtest material, or was it issued/published for another purpose?<sup>1</sup>**

---

<sup>1</sup>Besides the obvious desire to sell a product and earn revenue.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I am going to guess that your editing out of the secondary question means that  I probably need to ask that as a separate question? (That thought had crossed my mind as I finished my first edit.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes it was official playtest material

Viewing the product on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786964634) you can zoom in on the description on the back which states:

> ... can be played using the rules for 3rd Edition (v3.5), 4th Edition, and the D&D Next Playtest.

Comment: It would appear that I did not read the fine print on the back of what I bought?  When I get home, I guess I need to examine the packaging more closely.

Comment: It's odd that that info isn't on the WotC store page anyway. Oh well, a little bit of internet sleuthing got an answer!

Comment: You may want to add that the monster stats for three different editions are available at:http://media.wizards.com/downloads/dnd/MinBG_Statistics.pdf